# PAUSE in a batch script after passing text as an input to the command

Tags: windows, batch-file, input, io-redirection, pause

I wrote a simple batch script, say `script.cmd`, which is prompting for a several input variables, let's say(for simplicity):

```
set /p var1=
set /p var2=
*doing some really simple stuff here*
PAUSE
*more simple stuff here*
```

I tried to automate the input writing an `input.txt` file, let's say:

```
var1
var2
```

In the command prompt I type:

```
script.cmd < input.txt
```

Everything is executing exactly the same way it would if I had inputted the variables manually, save for the `PAUSE`: the execution does not stop at all.

Why would that be? Something to do with the input redirection? (if so, is there 
a way to turn back the focus back to the command prompt?)

PS: The same happens to `TIMETOUT`- looks like it gets skipped.

Comment: You could try timeout with /nobreak or use the old fashioned `ping -n %Secs% localhost`

Comment: that will surely do when it comes to timed paused, but what if I wanted to resume the process manually and at my discretion from the command line(by pressing any button)?

Comment: You can't disable or remove the input redirection after it has provided all the input it can. You either redirect input, or you don't. If you want more control you have to write a program that does this for you.

Comment: timeout.exe doesn't support input redirection. It only supports reading input from the console. The built-in `pause` command supports stdin redirected to a disk file or pipe, but using a file is pointless. Either there's a byte immediately available to read or it's at EOF. It makes more sense when stdin is redirected to a pipe, with input under the control of a user or program. Anyway, if you want to redirect its input back to the console, just use `pause < con`.

Comment: timeout.exe is trickier. It requires stdin to be opened in read-write mode, which is the norm for console handles because the console API requires it in general. Specifically in this case timeout calls `SetConsoleMode` on the input handle, which requires write access. In this case you need to use `conin$` instead of `con` and open stdin (0) in append mode, which looks a bit weird, e.g. `timeout 5 0>>conin$`.

Comment: thank you, eryksun, this is the way to do it! btw, is there a way to use the `.txt` file to initialize the first variable, `var1` in this case,  and then go back to the console to be prompted to input manually the next one, i.e. `var2`?